# How do I get sbt 0.10.0 to compile files in a subdirectory?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a build.sbt file in my project root.. all my source files live in the subdirectory src (and src/irc, src/xmpp).

Here is my build.sbt

> name := "mrtoms"
>
> organization := "chilon"
>
> scalaVersion := "2.9.0"
>
> version := "0.1"
>
> libraryDependencies ++= Seq("commons-httpclient" % "commons-httpclient" % "3.1")
>
> crossPaths := false
>
> scalaHome := Some(file("/usr/share/scala"))
>
> target := file("project/target")
>
> sourceDirectory := file("src")
>
> mainClass := Some("org.chilon.mrtoms.MrToms")

However sbt always just makes an empty jar file.

I tried putting build.sbt inside the "src" directory but then it missed out all the scala files in subdirectories of "src".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems that you need to provide path relative to the base directory. This should work for you (it replaces `sourceDirectory := file("src")`):

```
scalaSource in Compile <<= baseDirectory(_ / "src")
```

Some more information you can find in this thread:

http://groups.google.com/group/simple-build-tool/browse_thread/thread/095e87247d146fa7?fwc=1

Comment: when i add the above line to build.sbt im getting "Type error in expression"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the default convention then you need to override both scala and java source locations

```
scalaSource in Compile <<= baseDirectory(_ / "src")

javaSource in Compile <<= baseDirectory(_ / "src")
```